# Using Photo-Excel to insert a screenshot into Excel using RobotFramework+Sikuli+Python+Visual Studio code

Tags: python, excel, selenium, robotframework, sikuli

I am building a framework to automate a java applet application. As the name indicates, this application doesn't have any HTML. Using Robotframework-Selenium along with Sikuli to automate. I am required to use Visual Studio code. Now, my main goal of this automation is to somehow convert the table (excel like table in the applet) into an excel sheet and email to the client. I have automate the steps until the table in the applet opens. My idea is to take a screenshot of the table and insert that into excel sheet using Photo-excel. Python and Robot, sikuli are new tools for me. So I am not good at manipulating anything at this point. I have just learnt how to stand, but I need to run NOW. I need help. There are sample codes for photo-excel. but that's not enough for my knowledge. I don't know how to call the .py class in my .robot class to utilize the functions. I am open to other tools as long as it does what I am intending to do.

Comment: You should try to use the OCR commands in SikuliLibrary. You would use `Get Text` and then process it to save in a CSV file.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimum reproducable example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example